# Ubuntu 14.04 with 3D acceleration on virtual box freezes after save state

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, 3d

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running in Virtual Box with 3D acceleration enabled. When I save the state of the machine and then resume from that saved state, the system is completely unresponsive. I'm unable to take any action except for shutting off the power to the machine. If I turn off 3D acceleration, this problem disappears. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Here's some information on my setup:

Host: OS X 10.9.4

Virtual Box version: 4.3.14

Comment: I've experienced this as well, though I have not tried turning off 3D yet. This bug may match what you're seeing:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13487